# Why is Facebook javascript SDK slowing down page load speed?

Tags: facebook

We use the javascript SDK for login and sharing (iframes for the Like button).  Javascript is loaded after the page load. We're seeing 1.5 to 3 second slower full page loads with Facebook enabled. What can we do to identify the cause and optimize perceived and real page load speed?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure all JS includes are after CSS includes as for rending
2. Remote javascript loads are at the mercy of whoever is hosting them. Sometimes you can locally host them, but then you don't get the latest version, and some JS includes won't work if they're not included remotely.
3. Try putting the facebook include as the very last element in the  tag. The actual facebook logic won't happen until the rest of the document loads however.